# Android camera2 photo low quality

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm making an App to take pictures in a way, I implemented the sequential function but the photos are of poor quality and are not in focus, how could I improve? Thanks in advance.

```
if (null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
        return;
    }
    final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
    StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


    assert streamConfigurationMap != null;
    Size largest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)), new CompareSizesByArea());
    final ImageReader reader= ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);


    final List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation());
    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the first element of the list of supported output sizes will be the best. You must choose the size that suits you. If getOutputSizes() returns **null**, you should not try to create an ImageReader for 1280x720.

Comment: I modified the code inspired by the code of google samples but the quality does not increase, the photos are dark and unclear.

Comment: Is this specific for sequential pictures, or same poor quality reproduces when you take one? If the latter, try to compare your parameters and results to OpenCamera.